# Externally installing netwide assembler in Ubuntu

Tags: tar

I have downloaded the tar.gz file of nasm and extracted it on my desktop. But I don't know how to install it. Please can anyone tell me how to install nasm externally on Ubuntu.
Thanks in advanced

Comment: As 10.04 is EoL, this is off topic.

Comment: If I get a higher version of Ubuntu. Then how should I do it?

Comment: Look at [Ubuntu wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades) or [another askubuntu question](http://askubuntu.com/q/34430/295286) for upgrade instructions. Also, what dos that tar.gz contain ? Is there a README file ? Typically instructions are there . . .Sometimes there may be config or makefile files

Answer (score 1):

The general-purpose x86 assembler (nasm) is in the default repositories for all currently supported versions of Ubuntu. nasm can be installed with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install nasm
```

The version of nasm in the default Ubuntu 14.04 repositories is nasm 2.10.09 and the version for Ubuntu 16.04 is nasm 2.11.08 (which is also the latest stable version from the [official NASM website](http://www.nasm.us/)).